# how to pass two parameters into grid.appScope in ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, html, angular-ui-grid, celltemplate

I am trying to pass 2 parameters into the ui-grid cell template.

e.g: `ng-click="grid.appScope.copyOperation(row.entity, copyOperation)`.

copyOperation would obviously be a string.

**Reason**: Reduce redundancy in code by maintaining a single method for all the grid operations(delete, copy and edit) with if else conditions.

On the controller side, the function would be like

```
$scope.copyOperation= function(row, operation) {
//Do necessary steps by operation
};
```

But, unfortunately I get undefined in operation (No Errors). So, how do I pass a string in this case? Any alternate suggestions will also be helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that petty question.

```
ng-click="grid.appScope.copyOperation(row, \'copy\')
```

will let operation arg be set to copy.

Thanks!

Comment: but what can you do if you wish to pass other parameters? like something that you get from the user?